# 95% of root file system is in use but cannot see disk space issue

Tags: aws-ec2

1st of all, I'm a linux & AWS amateur, so I feel as if I'm searching in the dark here.
I seem to be getting issues with my Elastic Beanstalk environment. After a few days I get notifications of

> Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Warning. 1 out of 1 instances are impacted.

When I check the beanstalk instance, its saying

> 95 % of root file system is in use. 402 MB free.

This issue persists even when I restart the environment. However, when I redeploy the app to Beanstalk, it rectifies the issue, but it then comes back after a few days again.  I suspect a memory leak in my app code, but I haven't diagnosed it as yet.

`df -h` shows the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          16G  3.5G   12G  24% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme1n1     16G  3.5G   12G  24% /home
/dev/loop0      974M  2.3M  904M   1% /home/cloudshell-user
/dev/nvme0n1p1   30G   13G   17G  44% /aws/mde/mde
```

I've tried to confirm this root file system issue before proceeding, but cannot see what it taking up the space.  I've tried the following additional commands:

- `sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \`
- `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'`

With nothing obvious showing up. Does anyone have any ideas to help a newbie?

thanks in advance

Comment: Install ncdu and use that maybe that helps to see where the space is going.https://www.networkworld.com/article/970542/looking-at-linux-disk-usage-with-the-ncdu-command.html. I don't see the 402mb free in your df output, are you sure beanstalk is correct configured?

Comment: I tried installing and running ncdu too. I got nothing returned when I ran it. Having never used it before, I didn't know what to expect or whether I was doing something wrong.

And no, I'm not sure if beanstalk is configured correctly or not.

Comment: Ncdu should scan the disk and show disk space usage. Try this command `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /` If you identify a large directory, you can navigate into it and run the same command to drill down further.You may need root/sudo permissions to access some directories.

Comment: Also try `sudo df -h /`

Comment: I've had to redeploy again as it eventually fell over last night so I can't try these commands specifically. It doesn't make sense that the filesystem is getting filled up, it's a straightforward webapp. We store a few customer files on S3 but other than that I cannot think of a reason the filesystem is getting filled up. I'm beginning to think the logfiles might be at play here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to knowing some deleted files tricks, to manage a file system you need to know what type is on top, and what layers are on bottom.

Run the `mount` command to see the devices and options off all volumes. / on overlay means its upper directory is almost certainly on another file system, and the available space when you check it interactively reflects that. Monitoring could have a slightly different implementation, getting all block devices rather than mounted file systems.

Assess the size of upperdir, workdir, and lowerdir with `ncdu -x`  Note you can use the `-o` option to save file size for later analysis.

Storage use increases over time. Log files, cached and staged things, data that the application does not process as quickly as it should. Much of this could be temporary data with automatic purge processes, but verify that. Short of making things read only and not allowing any file writes, there needs to be enough space to continue operations until the problem can be fixed.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply John, but most of that is a different language to me. I'm struggling to get ncdu installed and active.

I ran the mount command, and it does come back with stuff, but I don't know what I'm looking at!

Comment: Learn about overlay file system on Linux, and find out on this host what exactly the top and bottom layers are.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figured it out. I was accessing the shell from the beanstalk env, but I should've been looking at the EC2 instance. Once on there, I was able to establish it was indeed the logs files that were the cause using du -h command. Thanks to all who replied and offered their help